# How can i add six to yocto image?

Tags: python, yocto, setuptools, six

**Hey There.**

I'm trying to add **six** to my **yocto** image, I saw there was a recipe in the **open-embedded** git but perhaps it was removed (in **python-devtools**, for some odd reason. I'm trying to "adapt" the old recipe into my layer but i get yet another error saying i need the setuptools recipe.

```
Could not inherit file classes/setuptools.bbclass
```

Can someone perhaps provide me a recipe for **setuptools** and **six**?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm wondering if you really need it and why. Anyhow, it's unclear what you did and what your problems are. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide your poky branch, your recipe content that provided the error and do you mean `python3-six` ?

Comment: Hi, i'm using the dunfell branch, and yes i meant python3-six